# Not all of the selected model is showing in the UV Editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to make a UV map of a MSFS 2020 addon aircraft for the purpose of painting a livery for the aircraft.  I am having an issue with getting my UV map to show completely, which is getting frustrating. The picture below hopefully shows what I mean.  I have selected all of the parts named specifically for this one file, and only a few of them show on the UV.  I can specifically select points on the model, from parts that are missing, and they don't show on the UV.

[image: Picture showing the selected parts on the right, and the UV map on the left]

Comment: Hello and welcome, you just need to turn on UV Sync https://imgur.com/a/jsQoBxv

Comment: I tried this, but I think the problem is that there is an importing issue.  Your solution unfortunately didn't help.